# Run JavaScript inside a PHP page in an Observer - Magento

Tags: php, javascript, magento

I have a module that contains an `Observer`, `Observer` obviously this is a PHP page but I need to run some scripts, JavaScript, made ​​using the `echo` but he just failing in some parts of Magento.
I would like to know any other alternate way beyond the `echo`.

Thank you.

Comment: I think your translator is just "falahando".

Comment: Sorry, I've accepted your edition

Answer (score 2):

you can try to include your code in separate .js file and include that file using XMl
below is sample layout code snippet

```
<layout>
<adminhtml_modifiedproduct_index>
<reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><file>modifiedproduct/datefilter.js</file></action>
</reference>
</adminhtml_modifiedproduct_index>
```

Comment: I liked the idea, but could tell me how do I do to call some function after this JS?

Comment: on which event you want to call the function

Comment: Well, I'll try to explain in a clear way. I have an Observer and it is being triggered a series of events that need, but some things have got to be javascript and ECHO does not work because it also puts the functions in my local it should not, such as the WSDL.
I declare my .Js and how do I access the functions for it later?